# Why the low mass resonance $K(1270)$ can decay into higher mass final states $K^*(1400)\pi$?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, experimental-physics, standard-model

I’ve seen same explaining that the mass of a decaying particle must exceed the sum of the masses of its daughter particle.
But Why the processes like **$K(1270)\to K^*_0(1400)\pi$ and $K_1^*(1400)\to K^*_1(1430)\pi$ could happen**? [PDGLive](https://pdglive.lbl.gov/Particle.action?init=0&node=M028&home=MXXX020)

Comment: Certainly, the $K_0^*(1400)$ and $K_1^*(1430)$ will decay soon.  Does this mean the resonances are virtual particles and they are not in the mass shell? Or generally speaking, all resonances decays don't obey the mass rules?

Comment: Provide their widths and discuss their overlaps!

Comment: Hi@CosmasZachos, Thanks for your tip. The PDG gives the mass and width of $K_1(1270)$ and $K_0^*(1430)$ by $\Gamma_{K_1 (1270)}=90\pm20$MeV, $M_{K_1(1270)}=1253\pm7$MeV, $\Gamma_{K_0^*(1430)}=270\pm80 $MeV, $M_{K_0^* (1430)}=1425\pm50$MeV. This decay only happens if the widths of the  $K_1$ and $K_0^*$ are token into account. Can I understand the decay in this way: It is impossible to judge whether decay can occur by mass alone. I have wrong impression in such decays.

Comment: Right. Think of masses as distributions, overlapping each other, with the Large widths thereof making such overlaps easy….

Comment: Thanks for your comment! @CosmasZachos

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check you this article: "Inconsistency of the data on the $K_1(1270) \rightarrow \pi K_0^⁎(1430)$ decay width" Physics Letters B
Volume 824, 10 January 2022, 136827  (https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S037026932100767X) where the decay is discussed in detail. In particular take a look at equation (9) and it's discussion.

Comment: Hi Dave, thanks for your reply! I really appreciate your help in answering my question! Cheers!

Comment: Greetings! Please consider expanding this answer to include the salient points of the linked paper. Our community prefers standalone answers over answers which require visiting an external page.